# A map of degree $d$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ admits infinitely many points of degree $d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is a smooth proper geometrically connected curve defined over a number field $k$. Suppose $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is a degree $d$ map. This means that after assigning coordinates $x$ and $y$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ and letting $T=x/y$, $[k(T):K(X)]=d$, where $K(X)$ is the function field of $X$. I'd like to know why this means that $X$ has infinitely many points of degree $d$, where we say that $P$ is a point of degree $d$ if $[K(P):K]=d$, where $K(P)$ is the residue field of $P$.
For instance, I'm not sure why this might suggest the fibers are of degree $d$. What am I missing?

Edit: We assume $k$ is a number field

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is true... the map $[x:y]\mapsto [x^d : y^d]$ is a degree $d$-map from $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ to itself but (if $k$ is algebraically closed, for instance) $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ has no degree $d$ points - in fact, no scheme has.

Comment: This is true if $k$ is Hilbertian (e.g., a number field)

Comment: I think over the complex numbers  this is never true?

Comment: If $X\to Y$ is of degree $d$ and $t:\mathrm{Spec} $ $k\to Y$ is a closed point, then the induced morphism $X_t\to \mathrm{Spec} $ $k$ is of degree $d$. That is, the scheme-theoretic fibres of $X\to Y$ are degree $d$ extensions of $k$. If $X_t$ is reduced, then you can write $X_t$ as a product of finite field extensions (whose collective degree equals $d$). If $X_t$ is reduced and irreducible, then $X_t$ is the spectrum of a field. That field will forcefully have degree $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^1_k$ be a finite surjective morphism of degree $d$, where $X$ is a smooth projective geometrically connected curve over $k$.

Hilbert's irreducibility theorem says that the set of $t\in \mathbb{P}^1(k)$ such that $X_t$ is integral is dense.

Now, if the fibre $X_t$ is integral, then $X_t = \mathrm{Spec} L$ with $L/k$ some finite field extension of degree $d$.